# Finding the row/position in a numpy array using a mouse over on a 2D dot plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D dot plot which I generated using matplotlib with 750 points on it. I was trying to use mpldatacursor so that I can mouse over the points to determine the label for a datapoint (i.e. row/position in the numpy array etc).

When I use mpldatacursor it works well - but I only get x & y co-ords. Any thoughts on how I might find the label/origin of the individual points of interest? I know I could plot labels - but with 750 datapoints it's pretty messy.

thoughts,
Sarr.

Comment: Just for whatever it's worth, if you just want the index of the point to be displayed, you'd just use `datacursor(formatter={ind}.format)`.  This will always display a list, even if there's only one element. If you'd prefer it to look a bit nicer, do something like `datacursor(formatter=lambda **kwargs: ', '.join(kwargs['ind']))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pick a plotted point, passing the information back in data coordinates. Check matplotlib's [event handling and picking](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) guide for detailed information on how to achieve this.

Once you have the data coordinates, you can find the corresponding indices using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# arr is the array you plot

[...code to plot/pick array...]

# datapt are the data coordinates you get back from the picking event

indices = np.argwhere(arr == datapt)
```

This approach involves a lot more work than mpldatacursor, but the latter doesn't seem to offer nearly as much flexibility.